# String Replace Line Breaks

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have read an entire file into a string object :-

```
string result = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TestLog.log");
```

I want to remove all line breaks, "\n", but i also need to preserve any instances in the string object where "\r\n" exists.

How can i do this?

Comment: C# supports lookbehind in regexen.  `(?<!\r)\n` should capture any `\n` not immediately preceded by `\r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result = result.Replace("\n","").Replace("\r","\r\n")`

Without using regex though. Not sure if you intend to use that or not.

Comment: What about if the file contains itself a "\r"?. Dont you are changing the text?

Comment: Yes, but that was not a requirement in the question.

Comment: Sure, but i think that not changing the content of original text is an implicit requirement ;)

Comment: I agree! I guess it's up to the asker if that might be a problem or not. Maybe it's a nice side effect ;)

Comment: You could first replace `\r\n` with something else. `result = result.Replace("\r\n", "__%rn__").Replace("\n","").Replace("__%rn__", "\r\n")`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Yes, but theoretically, `__%rn__` could also be present in the file and you end up with the same issue ;) You'd first have to find a string that is not present at all with 100% certainty... props if you can extend the single statement to fulfil that requirement! :)

Comment: @JohnWillemse Never in my life have I seen a file that contains `__%rn__` (other than this site now that I posted it). Also you could create a string that doesn't exist in the file with a `for` loop. Not sure if worth it thought.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen If "never in my life have I seen..." was a valid criterium in programming, there would be a heck of a lot more bugs around ;-) But I get your point!

Comment: How about looping through every char combination until you find one that's `not in file.read()`? For example, use a for loop to get `aaaa, aaab, aaac, ..., cazl, cazm, cazn, ...`. No file in the world can contain all combinations of say 7 characters.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want a regular expression replace.

```
string result = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TestLog.log");
string newresult = Regex.Replace(result, @"[^\\r]\\n", "");
```

So the pattern looks for any \n that is not preceded by \r.